# Call fnRowCallback on table redraw in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am doing some post processing in datatable in fnRowCallback. But they are not being called when the table is redrawn. (i.e, when some event like changing the number of displayed rows are called from UI, the table is redrawn)

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable = $('#data').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bSort": false,
                "sAjaxSource": "query.php",
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aoColumns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                ],
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                    $(nRow).attr("id", aData[4]);
                    return nRow;
                },
               "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                // How do I call fnRowCallback here? 
               // losing post processing because it is not being called after a redraw
                }
    });
```

Comment: Where is your code that redraws the table?

Comment: I don't manually redraw, but the table is redrawn automatically when pagination is used if I am correct. I just want to hook the code I use in rowcallback whenever the table is redrawn.

Comment: `fnRowCallback` should be called on each row every redraw, maybe try manually redrawing the table and seeing if `fnRowCallback` is called.

Comment: But how do I manually call redraw if datatable itself calls redraw during pagination or display number of rows change?

Comment: I meant call `oTable.fnDraw()` somewhere outside of the callbacks, just to make sure that `fnRowCallback` gets fired on all redraws, not just the initial draw.

Comment: Tried calling it, no use. I could not get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your attempt to look up the actual row via jquery in `$(nRow)` does not work. `nRow` contains the whole row. You should just is as namespace for the jquery selector (second parameter) to restrict it to this particular row.

Like so:

> $("selector",nRow).jqueryaction()

This works for me:

Html:

```
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td class="boldmetight">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="boldmetight">c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>.. etc
```

And the table definition with a rowcallback that bolds every cell with a specific class (just for example):

```
  var otable = $("#datatable").dataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
      $('.boldmetight', nRow).html('<b>' +  $('.boldmetight', nRow).text() + '</b>');
    }
  });
```

Look at this working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qh5sHOTFegiTceS6hwok?p=preview)

Comment: what is the 2nd param to the selector for? **$('.boldmetight', nRow)**

Comment: It limits the selector lookup to the html snippet contained in nRow, not the whole page.

Comment: this is a nice. Is it possible to add the class name to the selected row and not just one cell within that row...thanks.